# Is there anyone of troubleshooting or dealing with stack overflow errors when the trace shows nothing?

Tags: android

Got a trace like this:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:5160)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.widget.TableRow.getColumnsWidths(TableRow.java:308)
at android.widget.TableLayout.findLargestCells(TableLayout.java:497)
at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:462)
at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:428)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:696)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:306)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1135)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1200)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:805)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there anything that can be done here?
I'm getting reports of blank screens and force closes.

Comment: how ironic, a Stack Overflow error on SO.

Comment: Notice that the trace shows only android classes, nothing from my own app.

Comment: You got anything in the trace logs in eclipse?

Comment: I would like to see the xml layout you use. Maybe you have a circular dependency?

Comment: Heres my xml.  Few files in there.
http://pastebin.com/06yHt4eW

Answer (score 1):

When stack traces don't help the best thing you can do is trace it.

Start to scatter log messages through strategic parts of your application, and once you find where it is set some breakpoints and step through.

```
    Log.d("MyActivity", "MyClass.getView() — Initializing ");
```

Once you have your logs setup use [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html#logcat)

Comment: Why `Log.i` instead of `Log.d`?

Comment: Well, this didnt happen on my dev phone.  It was a trace I got from google that happened on some phone out there.  I seem to be getting force crashes on some phones (EVO 2.2) yet is works on other phones (N1, moto droid).  It would be nice if you could publish an app in BETA mode which get the dev more info like phone model, OS version, maybe some logging.